# Can I read mathematics book without solving any problem in it?

Tags: learning

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
In this book, there are too many problems for readers.
I want to understand this book but I don't want to solve problems if possible.
I want to finish reading this book as soon as possible.

Almost all mathematicians stress the importance of solving problems.
For example, James R. Munkres wrote:

> Working problems is a crucial part of learning mathematics. No one can learn topology merely by poring over the definitions, theorems, and examples that are worked out in the text.

Can I read mathematics book without solving any problem in it?

Comment: Problems solving is not optional. You do get to test your understanding and more importantly learn some key techniques which are not really a part of the theorems presented in text.

Comment: You won't understand the book if you do not solve exercises.

Comment: Also it is not necessary to solve all problems in one go. Luckily there is always the option to ask on mathse if you face any difficulty with a problem. Btw Herstein's book is great. It was the first book where I found a proof of transcendence of $e$.

Comment: Can you? Yes, but "can" is different from "should." (I would also take issue with "I want to finish reading this book as soon as possible" - that's fundamentally at odds with "I want to understand this book.")

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @markvs Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: I gave up the idea of reading this book rapidly and I try to solve all the problems in this book if possible. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: You are not new to mathematics. Have you ever learned any topic in math without doing the problems?

Comment: "Can I read mathematics book without solving any problem in it?"  No.  The police will come to your home and arrest you. "I want to finish reading this book as soon as possible." https://i.pinimg.com/originals/28/20/61/28206111af37e9010f7a34795f472b15.gif "I want to understand this book" Ah... well, no we are talking.  You will have to figure out the best way to do this and skipping problems and speed reading will seriously hinder understanding.

Comment: You need not solve ALL of the problems in order to understand the subject, but if you pay attention to what the problems say, you may see that you need some of them.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you very much for your comment. I tend to skip problems in a math book. Skipping problems and speed reading strategy look good to me.  I need to change my mind.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much for your comment. I prefer all or nothing. It is difficult for me to select important problems for me.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you very much for your comment. When reading about a subject for the first time, I usually skip all the problems in the book. Instead I try to solve examples in a math book without reading the solution which the author gave. And after I am familiar with the subject, sometimes I solve problems. Anyway, I tend to prefer passive learning.